# Angular 2 add a string(css-class) to parent Component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

How may I add a string(css-class) to the parent Component?
Different pages should be able to add a class to the container element.

*app.component.ts:*

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
        <div class="container {{ ADD HERE }}">
             <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

---

*page1.component.ts:*

```ts
@Component({
  template: `
      <p>I'm page 1!</p>
  `
})
export class Page1Component {
      containerClasses = "page-1";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```ts
@Component({
  template: `
      <p>I'm page 1!</p>
  `
})
export class APageComponent {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {
  }

  containerClasses = "page-1";

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.parentElement.classList.add(this.containerClasses);
  }
}
```

Comment: I may also want to share more informations like "display the header?" from child to parent component. Also the element must not be the parent in dom to access it with nativeElement.parentElement

Comment: Sure, you can always use a shared service for component communication https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: This was a huge help for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @SuttonY glad to hear :)